# Orderby Timestamp column in MySQL with hibernate Criteria API throws error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate to retrieve data from a MySQL database.

```
    @Transactional
    public List<PendingDomainEntity> listPendingDomain(int count, int offset)
            throws DaoException {
        try {
            Criteria listCriteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(PendingDomainEntity.class);
            listCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc("domaincreateddt"));
            listCriteria.setMaxResults(count);
            listCriteria.setFirstResult(offset);
            Criterion domainstatus = Restrictions.eq("domainstatus", "Pending").ignoreCase();
            listCriteria.add(domainstatus);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<PendingDomainEntity> pendingDomainList = (List<PendingDomainEntity>) listCriteria.list();
            LOGGER.debug("Regg-Service: The pending domain list is:={}", pendingDomainList);
            return pendingDomainList;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception: Service: Error while retrieving the pending domains list");
            throw new DaoException(ex.getMessage(), Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

This is how domainCreatedDt is declared in PendingDomainEntity class

```
@Column(name = "DOMAINCREATEDDT")
private Timestamp domainCreatedDt;
```

I get following exception message

```
could not resolve property: domaincreateddt of: mypackage.DTO.PendingDomainEntity
```

But when I use a different column name for Order, it works fine. Are there any restrictions for order by on timestamp columns ?

Comment: Could it be case sensitivity? Try "domainCreateDdt" (or similar) to match your getter name

Comment: @Bohemian I tried all letter cases. I also tried on another column that has timestamp data type and that din't work as well. However, when I tried on non-timestamp column, the code worked.

Comment: Could you please append the definition of the DomainPendingClass along with the mappings?

Comment: @JorgeGarita, sorry I did not understand that. Did you want me to post PendingDomainEntity class code ? I updated with the declaration code of domainCreatedDt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this documentation chapter about HQL *(the same applies to Criteria API)*:

#### [16.1. Case Sensitivity](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-casesensitivity)

> **With the exception of names of Java classes and properties**, queries are case-insensitive. So SeLeCT is the same as sELEct is the same as SELECT, but org.hibernate.eg.FOO is not org.hibernate.eg.Foo, and foo.barSet is not foo.BARSET....

This is the JAVA name:

```
private Timestamp domainCreatedDt;
```

and that means, that this is **NOT** the same:

```
listCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc("domaincreateddt"));
```

Simply it must be **`domainCreatedDt`**

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I was under the impression that it should be actual column name.

Comment: Great to see that... really JAVA names must fit to their mapping. Enjoy Hiberante ;)